# How to clear CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int' and CS1729 C# 'Car' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#

I cant figure out what to change. I have played with the void and int.

The problem is with the `SlowDown` and `SpeedUp` methods, and in the lines `Car car1 = new Car("Ford", "Focus", 2010, car1Speed);` The CS1729 is flagging the Car before the `("Ford", "Focus", 2010, car1Speed)`.

How do I fix these errors?

```
class Car
{
    private int Speed;
    private string Make;
    private string Model;
    private int Year;

    public void Car1(string make, string model, int year, int speed)
    {
        this.Make = make;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Speed = speed;
    }
    public void Car2(string make, string model, int year, int speed)
    {
        this.Make = make;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Speed = 0;
    }
    public void SpeedUp()
    {
        Speed = Speed ++;
    }


    public void SlowDown()
    {
        Speed = Speed --;
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Year + " " + Make + " " + Model + " is going " + Speed + " MPH.");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int car1Speed = 20;
        int car2Speed = 0;
        Car car1 = new Car("Ford", "Focus", 2010, car1Speed);
        Car car2 = new Car("Chevy", "Cruze", 2018, car2Speed);

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                car2Speed = car2.SpeedUp();
            }
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                car1Speed = car1.SpeedUp();
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                car1Speed = car1.SlowDown();
                car2Speed = car2.SlowDown();
            }
        }
        car1.Display();
        car2.Display();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: When you don't really understand something, you can ask someone, and you will get the answer, but at this time you really should go an see the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: The two errors you are dealing with are that the `Car` class has no explicit constructor, only the default which is used like `new Car()`, and that the `SpeedUp` and `SlowDown` methods are not returning a result that can be assigned to `car1Speed` or `car2Speed`.
Some suggestions are you need to look at making your methods have a return type of `int` for changing the speed, and change your Car1 method to a constructor by removing the return type so it is declared as `public Car(string make, string model, int year, int speed)`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered in your comments it seems this is one of those **bad assignments** where they teach you **bad coding practices** by providing poorly written code. This is disastrous practice that poisons the industry because bad habits don't come off easily. Here is the full code how it should be written and comments why it should be that way.

```
public class Car
{
    // Member fields should be either "_camelCase" or "camelCase"
    private string _make;
    private string _model;
    private int _year;
    private int _speed;

    // Don't duplicate the code, default value for speed makes it optional parameter. 
    // There is no need for a second constructor.
    public Car(string make, string model, int year, int speed = 0)
    {
        _make = make;
        _model = model;
        _year = year;
        _speed = speed;
    }

    public int SpeedUp()
    {
        // Increments speed and returns the value.
        // Might as well be void without return since example doesn't use it anywhere.
        return _speed++;
    }

    public int SlowDown()
    {
        // If speed is more than 1, decrement and then return the value
        return _speed > 0 ? _speed-- : 0;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        // String interpolations are much easier to read
        Console.WriteLine($"{_year} {_make} {_model} is going {_speed} MPH.");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    // Main is entry point for your app, it doesn't belong in any type class like Car, 
    // because it's not relevant to it
    private static void Main()
    {
        // Use descriptive names for variables, you already know one car is Ford and the 
        // other is Chevy so name them as such so you know which is which
        // later in the code. 
        var fordCar = new Car("Ford", "Focus", 2010, 20);
        var chevyCar = new Car("Chevy", "Cruze", 2018); // No speed parameter

        // Ommited variables car1Speed, car2Speed. You shouldn't declare variables 
        // that serve no purpose and aren't even in use.

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Returns int, but variable assignment ins't necessary to anything here
                chevyCar.SpeedUp(); 
            }
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                fordCar.SpeedUp();
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                fordCar.SlowDown();
                chevyCar.SlowDown();
            }
        }

        fordCar.Display();
        chevyCar.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: 4. Add two constructors in class Car:

a. One that accepts 4 parameters: make, model, year, and speed (in that order).
b. One that accepts make, model and year (assign a value of 0 to Speed).
 and the car2Speed = car2.SpeedUp(); is my teachers code i have to apply. all the main is teacher code i just have to fix the class to make the main work

Comment: 5. Add methods called SpeedUp() and SlowDown() in class Car.  These should increment or decrement the value of this.Speed repectively.  Only decrement if the value is greater than 0. Both should return the value of Speed after incrementing or decrementing the value.

Comment: Rewrote the answer how the code should look like bar poorly written assignment, this will help you more in the long run than just clearing up the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is a single *constructor* with an *optional* parameter

```
class Car
{

    public void Car(string make, string model, int year, int speed = 0)
    {
        this.Make = make;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Speed = speed;
    }

    ...
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)
- [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: 4. Add two constructors in class Car:

a. One that accepts 4 parameters: make, model, year, and speed (in that order).
b. One that accepts make, model and year (assign a value of 0 to Speed).